# How to add dependencies automatically in netcore2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have multiple pair of interface and implement like that

```
ICategoryService -> CategoryService
ICategoryTypeService -> CategoryTypeService
IOrderService -> OrderService
ILoggingService -> LoggingService
```

All classes and interfaces are in `Data.dll` and I loop it like this.

```
foreach (var type in serviceAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.Name.Contains("Repository") && !type.IsInterface && !type.IsGenericType)
    {
        Type interfaceImplement = type.GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType == false);

        if (interfaceImplement != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{type.Name} is inherited by {interfaceImplement.Name}");
            services.AddTransient(interfaceImplement, type);
        }
    }
}
```

and I get this error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'VietWebSite.Service.ILoggingService' while attempting to activate 'VietWebSite.Web.Areas.WebApi.Administrator.ValuesController'.

but it works if I change my code to be like that:

```
services.AddTransient<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();
services.AddTransient<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
services.AddTransient<ICategoryTypeService, CategoryTypeService>();
services.AddTransient<IOrderService, OrderService>();
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the line `type.Name.Contains("Repository")` be `type.Name.Contains("Service")`?

Comment: Sorry. It is my mistake. I changed to Service but i still get the same error

Comment: Does debug output contain all the types needed?

Comment: By the way, there are libraries that can do the same task, e.g. https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

Comment: I debuged and they were null

Comment: what `serviceAssembly.GetTypes()` returns?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a breakpoint at the registration? Also, have you confirmed that `serviceAssembly.GetTypes()` returns the types you expect?

Comment: Ok i will try although i want only use netcore library. Thanks

Comment: What is the value for `serviceAssembly`? While debugging, does this line `services.AddTransient(interfaceImplement, type);` run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

1. Create `Data` library with class and interface:

   ```
   public interface ICategoryService
   {
       string Output();
   }
   public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
   {
       public string Output()
       {
           return "CategoryService.Output";
       }
   }
   public interface ILoggingService
   {
       string Output();
   }
   public class LoggingService : ILoggingService
   {
       public string Output()
       {
           return "LoggingService.Output";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add `Data` library reference to asp.net core project
3. Configure `Startup.cs` like

   ```
   var serviceAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CategoryService));
   foreach (var type in serviceAssembly.GetTypes())
   {
       if (type.Name.Contains("Service") && !type.IsInterface && !type.IsGenericType)
       {
           Type interfaceImplement = type.GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType == false);

           if (interfaceImplement != null)
           {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{type.Name} is inherited by {interfaceImplement.Name}");
               services.AddTransient(interfaceImplement, type);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use Case:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;
       public HomeController(ILoggingService loggingService)
       {
           _loggingService = loggingService;
       }
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           var result = _loggingService.Output();
           return View();
       }        
   }
   ```

**Update**:

Your issue is caused by that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` will only return loaded assemblies, try code below:

```
//Load Assemblies
//Get All assemblies.
var refAssembyNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetReferencedAssemblies();
//Load referenced assemblies
foreach (var asslembyNames in refAssembyNames)
{
    Assembly.Load(asslembyNames);
}
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var myAssemblies = assemblies.Where(assem => assem.GetName().Name.Contains("VietWebSite.Data") || assem.GetName().Name.Equals("VietWebSite.Service"));
```

Comment: My way is the same of you, but it is not working, Please see images [img1](https://imgur.com/eXBNXNZ), [img2](https://imgur.com/vD0jWX6), [img3](https://imgur.com/mKKQpdA)

Comment: I shared zip file at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14rND5SLVmyurgpJExfNjo3s-pHq7_qpU/view?usp=sharing). You can download and run the api (/admin/api/values)

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

How you have done it is the correct manual way of doing it. There isn’t an automatic way of injecting dependencies I am aware of inbuilt, but there are packages available which do such as AutoFac https://autofac.org/.

Comment: Any way to do that ?  because i do not include autofac